# streaming, wrapping Javascript Div

Tags: javascript, animation

Is there a way to wrap this div so that content that goes off the screen on the right immediately appears on the left?

Basically, I just need it to loop.

HTML

```
<div id="contents">
    <div id="join">

    </div>
</div>
```

JS
    var currentPos = 0;
    var intervalHandle;

```
function beginAnimate() {
    document.getElementById("join").style.position = "absolute";
    document.getElementById("join").style.left = "0px";
    // document.getElementById("join").style.top = "100px";
    // cause the animateBox function to be called
    intervalHandle = setInterval(animateBox,30);
}

function animateBox() {
    //set new position
    currentPos+=5;
    document.getElementById("join").style.left = currentPos + "px";
    //
    if ( currentPos > innerWidth) {
        //clear interval
        clearInterval(intervalHandle);
        currentPos = 0;
        //reset custom inline style
        beginAnimate();

        //document.getElementById("join").style.top = "";
    }
}


function preparePage() {
    document.getElementById("join").onclick = function() {
        if ( document.getElementById("join").className == "callOut") {
            document.getElementById("join").className = "";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("join").className = "callOut";
        }
    };
}


window.onload = function() {
    preparePage();
    beginAnimate();
    animateBox();
}
```

Comment: There's no built-in support for this that I'm aware of. The most straightforward thing to do would be to simulate the effect by creating a clone of the content that you want to loop, positioning it outside of the viewport on the left, and then simultaneously animating both elements such that the right one appears to loop from the left.

Comment: you mean that you need `join` div to move from left to right inside `contents` div as if it was a window and loop the animation?

Comment: @MaveRick, yes i believe that is the best way of putting it.